# q kdb rank function with duplicated ranks

Tags: kdb, ranking, rank, ranking-functions

What would be an implementation of a q kdb function that does the same thing as the `rank` function but returns duplicated rank numbers for equal values?

In the standard implementation

```
rank 2 7 4 3 19 16 15 20 25 16 19
```

gives:

```
0 3 2 1 7 5 4 9 10 6 8
```

But I am looking for:

```
0 3 2 1 6 5 4 7 8 5 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do that by using `distinct` to remove duplicates, applying `rank` to that list and then creating a dictionary to map those rankings back to the original list.

```
q)list:2 7 4 3 19 16 15 20 25 16 19

/ creating the dictionary
q)d!rank d:distinct list
2 | 0
7 | 3
4 | 2
3 | 1
19| 6
16| 5
15| 4
20| 7
25| 8

/ wrapping this up in a function
q)rankDistinct:{(d!rank d:distinct x)x}

/ applying to the list
q)rankDistinct list
0 3 2 1 6 5 4 7 8 5 6
```

Or alternatively you could sort the `distinct` elements and then use find `?` to get the ranking by finding the index of where list elements appear in the distinct sorted elements.

```
q)rankDistinct2:{(asc distinct x)?x}

q)rankDistinct2 list
0 3 2 1 6 5 4 7 8 5 6
```